# SQL Primary Key (ID) Auto start from beginning

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, mongodb, auto-increment

I am using a 3rd party pricing API, the data is with start and end date with a price. I have checked that SQL database limits as follows;

```
BIGINT    Integer data from -2^63 through 2^63 - 1

INT       Integer data from -2^31 through 2^31 - 1

SMALLINT  Integer data from -2^15 through 2^15 - 1

TINYINT   Integer data from 0     through 255
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261815/upper-limit-for-autoincrement-primary-key-in-sql-server)

When data comes, I remove the data inside the table and create new ones. Because date range always changes.

So imagine some how, I hit the max identity number value in table. But at that point there are actually maximum 300.000 rows in the table. Can I start the identity number from 0 or 1 ? or do I have to use mongodb?

So, at the same there are 300.000 rows.

Best,

Comment: As per your question heading you can reset the identity column values but you can not use the values from start without removing the previous values from that table as you are saying it is the primary key column.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't represent an issue with data being uniquely identified:

You can directly use `TRUNCATE` instead, it resets the identity. But it might require higher privileges.

Or `DELETE`and reset the identity with `DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table', RESEED, 1)`

Comment: But this is a manual action right? Can we create a function that checks the identity number and resets the identity when it reaches to max?

Comment: @Shalafister's, In that case, you can either create a SQL Server trigger or schedule a SQL Server job to check and reset the value as well as. You can write the mail functionality also to notify the max values.

Comment: @Shalafister's : you can use a stored procedure that you associate with a daily SQL job whenever your identity counter is close from limit

Comment: @SurajKumar most of the cases, it is not very adviced to use SQL triggers

Comment: @m4s4mun3 It depends so I have given different options other than triggers like SQL Server and also to get the notified by the database mail system and get job done manually or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you use BIGINT identity column as primary key. The max value is 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. This means that if you add, say, 10,000 rows / second to the table for the for the foreseeable future (and beyond), it will take you:

9,223,372,036,854,775,807 / (10,0000 * 60 (sec) * 60 (min) * 24 (hour) * 365 (day))

=> 29 247 120 years until you reach the max value. (And the calculation does not even take leap years into account.)

So, if I were you, I would not worry about running out of ID's.

Comment: This is a very interesting fact.